# Jenkins Rake Unit Test Task Output Missing

Tags: jenkins, rake, rake-task

I am using Jenkins v1.467 for Continuous Integration for multiple ruby administration scripts (not rails). I noticed when i run it locally the output looks normal but when I see the jenkins log it doesnt print the unit test output.

Jenkins Output

```
    [SEACE API - Build and Unit Test] $ rake TESTOPTS=-v
    /usr/local/bin/ruby -w -I"lib" -I"/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1"               "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/parser-test.rb" "test/url-mapper-test.rb" -v
    => Execute Unit Tests
```

Running locally

```
TestMapper: 
  test_map_all:                     /Users/lmayorga/GitRepositories/seaceapi/src/mapper.rb:44:in `map_attributes': warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/Users/lmayorga/GitRepositories/seaceapi/test/url-mapper-test.rb:26:in `test_map_all': warning: URI.escape is obsolete
.: (0.000954)
  test_no_parameters:                   /Users/lmayorga/GitRepositories/seaceapi/src/mapper.rb:44:in `map_attributes': warning: URI.escape is obsolete
/Users/lmayorga/GitRepositories/seaceapi/test/url-mapper-test.rb:34:in `test_no_parameters': warning: URI.escape is obsolete
.: (0.000633)
TestParser: 
  test_contains_bases_link:             .: (3.745998)
  test_contains_name:                   .: (3.204862)
  test_contains_region:                 .: (3.062733)
  test_contains_valid_date:             .: (3.188995)
  test_get_all:                     .: (3.231105)
```

I think my Rake file test task looks pretty ok.

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.warning = true
  t.verbose = true
  t.test_files = FileList['test/*-test.rb']
end
```

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you need any other environment variables for running the rake task? All variables are not available in the Jenkins build.